# PHP/Openssl - error:1c800064:provider routines::bad decrypt

Tags: php, ubuntu, encryption, openssl

I want to encrypt and decrypt a gzip file with openssl. When I am trying to decrypt my encrypt file I have this openssl error : error:1c800064:provider routines::bad decrypt. I verified that the keys and IVs are the same with bool variable of php as you will can see in my code (Merge try). If someone could help me.

Setup :

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- PHP 8.1.22 (cli)
- Openssl 3.0.2

Encrypt part :

```
$key = $db->fetch_object($resql);
 print $key->pass_crypted . "\n";
 $key->pass_crypted = substr($key->pass_crypted, 0, 32);
 print $key->pass_crypted . "\n";
 
 if ($key === false) {
     die("Aucune clé n'a été trouvée dans la base de données.");
 }
 
 $outputFilePath = $outputdir . "/c" . $file . ".gz";
 
 // Vérification si le fichier source existe
 $sourceFilePath = $outputdir . "/" . $file . ".gz";
 if (!file_exists($sourceFilePath)) {
     die("Le fichier source n'existe pas : " . $sourceFilePath);
 }
 
 // Vecteur d'initialisation (IV) (128 bits, 16 octets)
 $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
 print $iv . "\n";
 

// Solution par morceau
// Ouvrir le fichier source en lecture
$sourceFile = fopen($sourceFilePath, 'r');
if (!$sourceFile) {
    die("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier source : $sourceFilePath");
}

// Ouvrir le fichier de sortie en écriture
$outputFile = fopen($outputFilePath, 'w');
if (!$outputFile) {
    die("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier de sortie : $outputFilePath");
}

if (fwrite($outputFile, $iv) === false) {
    die("Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier chiffré.");
}

// Définir la taille du morceau (en octets)
$chunkSize = 1024; // 1 Mo

while (!feof($sourceFile)) {
    // Lire un morceau du fichier source
    $chunk = fread($sourceFile, $chunkSize);
    if ($chunk === false) {
        die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier source.");
    }

    // Chiffrer le morceau
    $encryptedChunk = openssl_encrypt($chunk, 'aes-256-cbc', $key->pass_crypted, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    if ($encryptedChunk === false) {
        die("Erreur lors du chiffrement du morceau.");
    }

    // Écrire le morceau chiffré dans le fichier de sortie
    if (fwrite($outputFile, $encryptedChunk) === false) {
        die("Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier chiffré.");
    }
}

// Fermer les fichiers
fclose($sourceFile);
fclose($outputFile);

echo "Le fichier a été chiffré avec succès.\n";

// Supprimer le fichier source
if (!unlink($sourceFilePath)) {
    die("Erreur lors de la suppression du fichier source.");
}
```

Decrypt part :

```
<?php
$key = 'key'; //Modifiable

$inputFilePath = "/var/www/html/dolibarr/doc/admin/documents/cdocuments_dolibarr-lm_17.0.3_20230918122547.tar.gz"; //Modifiable

$decryptedFilePath = "cdocuments_dolibarr-lm_17.0.3_20230918103956.tar.gz"; //Modifiable

// Vérification si le fichier chiffré existe
if (!file_exists($inputFilePath)) {
    die("Le fichier chiffré n'existe pas : " . $inputFilePath);
}

// Ouvrir le fichier chiffré
if (! $encryptedFile = fopen($inputFilePath, "r")) {
    die("Erreur lors de l'ouverture du fichier chiffré.");
}

//Ouvrir le fichier déchiffré
if (! $decryptedFile = fopen($decryptedFilePath, "w")) {
    die("Erreur lors de l'ouverture du fichier déchiffré.");
}

$chunkSize = 1024;

// Récupération de l'IV (16 premiers octets)
if (! $iv = fread($encryptedFile, 16)) {
    die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier chiffré.");
}
print $iv . "\n";


// Ecriture du fichier déchiffré
while (!feof($encryptedFile)) {
    if (! $encryptedData = fread($encryptedFile, $chunkSize)) {
        die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier chiffré.");
    }

    $decryptedData = openssl_decrypt($encryptedData, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

    if ($decryptedData === false) {
        print openssl_error_string();
        die("Erreur lors du déchiffrement.");
    }

    if (! fwrite($decryptedFile, $decryptedData)) {
        die("Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier déchiffré.");
    }
}

echo "Le fichier a été déchiffré avec succès dans : " . $decryptedFilePath . "\n";


?>
```

Merge try :

```
$key = $db->fetch_object($resql);
 print $key->pass_crypted . "\n";
 $key->pass_crypted = substr($key->pass_crypted, 0, 32);
 print $key->pass_crypted . "\n";
 
 if ($key === false) {
     die("Aucune clé n'a été trouvée dans la base de données.");
 }
 
 $outputFilePath = $outputdir . "/c" . $file . ".gz";
 
 // Vérification si le fichier source existe
 $sourceFilePath = $outputdir . "/" . $file . ".gz";
 if (!file_exists($sourceFilePath)) {
     die("Le fichier source n'existe pas : " . $sourceFilePath);
 }
 
 // Vecteur d'initialisation (IV) (128 bits, 16 octets)
 $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
 print $iv . "\n";
 

// Solution par morceau
// Ouvrir le fichier source en lecture
$sourceFile = fopen($sourceFilePath, 'r');
if (!$sourceFile) {
    die("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier source : $sourceFilePath");
}

// Ouvrir le fichier de sortie en écriture
$outputFile = fopen($outputFilePath, 'w');
if (!$outputFile) {
    die("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier de sortie : $outputFilePath");
}

if (fwrite($outputFile, $iv) === false) {
    die("Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier chiffré.");
}

// Définir la taille du morceau (en octets)
$chunkSize = 1024; // 1 Mo

while (!feof($sourceFile)) {
    // Lire un morceau du fichier source
    $chunk = fread($sourceFile, $chunkSize);
    if ($chunk === false) {
        die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier source.");
    }

    // Chiffrer le morceau
    $encryptedChunk = openssl_encrypt($chunk, 'aes-256-cbc', $key->pass_crypted, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    if ($encryptedChunk === false) {
        die("Erreur lors du chiffrement du morceau.");
    }

    // Écrire le morceau chiffré dans le fichier de sortie
    if (fwrite($outputFile, $encryptedChunk) === false) {
        die("Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier chiffré.");
    }
}

// Fermer les fichiers
fclose($sourceFile);
fclose($outputFile);

echo "Le fichier a été chiffré avec succès.\n";

// Supprimer le fichier source
if (!unlink($sourceFilePath)) {
    die("Erreur lors de la suppression du fichier source.");
}

/*
 * Fin Chiffrement de l'archive (symétrique)
 */


$key2 = $key->pass_crypted; //Modifiable
print "flag_key : ";
$flag_key = $key->pass_crypted == $key2;
var_dump($flag_key);
print "\n";

$inputFilePath = $outputFilePath; //Modifiable

$decryptedFilePath = $outputdir . "/" . $file . ".gz"; //Modifiable

// Vérification si le fichier chiffré existe
if (!file_exists($inputFilePath)) {
    die("Le fichier chiffré n'existe pas : " . $inputFilePath);
}

// Ouvrir le fichier chiffré
if (! $encryptedFile = fopen($inputFilePath, "r")) {
    die("Erreur lors de l'ouverture du fichier chiffré.");
}

//Ouvrir le fichier déchiffré
if (! $decryptedFile = fopen($decryptedFilePath, "w")) {
    die("Erreur lors de l'ouverture du fichier déchiffré.");
}

$chunkSize = 1024;

// Récupération de l'IV (16 premiers octets)
if (! $iv2 = fread($encryptedFile, 16)) {
    die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier chiffré.");
}
print $iv2 . "\n";
print "flag_iv : ";
$flag_iv = $iv == $iv2;
var_dump($flag_iv);
print "\n";


// Ecriture du fichier déchiffré
while (!feof($encryptedFile)) {
    if (! $encryptedData = fread($encryptedFile, $chunkSize)) {
        die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier chiffré.");
    }
    
    $decryptedData = openssl_decrypt($encryptedData, 'aes-256-cbc', $key2, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv2);
    
    print $key2 . "\n";
    if ($decryptedData === false) {
        print openssl_error_string();
        die("Erreur lors du déchiffrement.\n");
    }
    
    if (! fwrite($decryptedFile, $decryptedData)) {
        die("Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier déchiffré.");
    }
}

echo "Le fichier a été déchiffré avec succès dans : " . $decryptedFilePath . "\n";
```

I also tried to open files in binary mode, but without success. (My IVs were not the same)

**Edit**

@Sammitch so I tried to implement your proposal but I have the same error : error:1C800064:Provider routines::bad decrypt.

```php
$resql = $db->query($sql);

if ($resql === false) {
    die("Erreur lors de la requête SQL : " . $db->lasterror());
}
 
$key = $db->fetch_object($resql);
print $key->pass_crypted . "\n";
$key->pass_crypted = substr($key->pass_crypted, 0, 32);
print $key->pass_crypted . "\n";

if ($key === false) {
    die("Aucune clé n'a été trouvée dans la base de données.");
}
 
$outputFilePath = $outputdir . "/c" . $file . ".gz";

// Vérification si le fichier source existe
$sourceFilePath = $outputdir . "/" . $file . ".gz";
if (!file_exists($sourceFilePath)) {
    die("Le fichier source n'existe pas : " . $sourceFilePath);
}

// Solution par morceau
// Ouvrir le fichier source en lecture
$sourceFile = fopen($sourceFilePath, 'r');
if (!$sourceFile) {
    die("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier source : $sourceFilePath");
}

// Ouvrir le fichier de sortie en écriture
$outputFile = fopen($outputFilePath, 'w');
if (!$outputFile) {
    die("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier de sortie : $outputFilePath");
}

// Définir la taille du morceau (en octets)
$chunkSize = 1024; // 1 Mo

while (!feof($sourceFile)) {
    // Vecteur d'initialisation (IV) (128 bits, 16 octets)
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

    // Lire un morceau du fichier source
    $chunk = fread($sourceFile, $chunkSize);
    if ($chunk === false) {
        die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier source.");
    }

    // Chiffrer le morceau
    $encryptedChunk = openssl_encrypt($chunk, 'aes-256-cbc', $key->pass_crypted, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    if ($encryptedChunk === false) {
        die("Erreur lors du chiffrement du morceau.");
    }

    // Écrire le morceau chiffré dans le fichier de sortie
    if (fwrite($outputFile, $encryptedChunk) === false) {
        die("Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier chiffré.");
    }

    if (fwrite($outputFile, $iv) === false) {
        die("Erreur lors de l'écriture du IV dans le fichier chiffré.");
    }
}

// Fermer les fichiers
fclose($sourceFile);
fclose($outputFile);

echo "Le fichier a été chiffré avec succès.\n";

// Supprimer le fichier source
if (!unlink($sourceFilePath)) {
    die("Erreur lors de la suppression du fichier source.");
}

/*
 * Fin Chiffrement de l'archive (symétrique)
 */


$key2 = $key->pass_crypted; //Modifiable
print "flag_key : ";
$flag_key = $key->pass_crypted == $key2;
var_dump($flag_key);
print "\n";

$inputFilePath = $outputFilePath; //Modifiable

$decryptedFilePath = $outputdir . "/" . $file . ".gz"; //Modifiable

// Vérification si le fichier chiffré existe
if (!file_exists($inputFilePath)) {
    die("Le fichier chiffré n'existe pas : " . $inputFilePath);
}

// Ouvrir le fichier chiffré
if (! $encryptedFile = fopen($inputFilePath, "r")) {
    die("Erreur lors de l'ouverture du fichier chiffré.");
}

//Ouvrir le fichier déchiffré
if (! $decryptedFile = fopen($decryptedFilePath, "w")) {
    die("Erreur lors de l'ouverture du fichier déchiffré.");
}

$chunkSize = 1024;

// Ecriture du fichier déchiffré
while (!feof($encryptedFile)) {
    if (! $encryptedData = fread($encryptedFile, $chunkSize)) {
        die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier chiffré.");
    }
    
    // Récupération de l'IV (16 dernies octets du chunk)
    if (! $iv2 = fread($encryptedFile, 16)) {
        die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier chiffré.");
    }

    $decryptedData = openssl_decrypt($encryptedData, 'aes-256-cbc', $key2, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv2);

    if ($decryptedData === false) {
        print openssl_error_string();
        die("Erreur lors du déchiffrement.\n");
    }
    
    if (! fwrite($decryptedFile, $decryptedData)) {
        die("Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier déchiffré.");
    }
}

echo "Le fichier a été déchiffré avec succès dans : " . $decryptedFilePath . "\n";
```

Comment: Your decrypt breaks because you're reading the first 1024 bytes off the file, which includes the 16-byte IV. You should read 16 for the IV and _then_ 1024 byte chunks. Your _process_ is broken as you're using the same IV for every chunk which both greatly weakens the encryption, and ensures that the encrypted files cannot be decrypted by anything that doesn't know your broken implementation. [this is also bad] Use the last 16 bytes of each chunk as the IV for the next and enjoy both improved security and compatibility.

Comment: @Sammitch 
I agree for the strongness of my process but I think I am reading the IV with this line :  
`if (! $iv2 = fread($encryptedFile, 16)) {  
    die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier chiffré.");  
}`

Comment: @Sammitch I tried your proposal but I have the same error : error:1C800064:Provider routines::bad decrypt. You can see the code in edited post.

Comment: The issue in your implementation logic is that you do not take into account the padding of the individual chunks during decryption. For encryption you use a chunk size of 1024 bytes. Since 1024 bytes equals an integer multiple of the AES block size (16 bytes), PKCS#7 pads with a whole block, i.e. the ciphertext is 1024 + 16 bytes. Accordingly, a chunk size of 1024 + 16 bytes must be used for decryption.

Comment: It would be more efficient (with a chunk size of 1024 bytes) to disable padding except for the last chunk (keep in mind that if the plaintext of the last chunk is 1024 bytes, the ciphertext is 1024 + 16 bytes, otherwise 1024 bytes). Additionally you should use as IV for the second and the following chunks the last block of the ciphertext of the previous chunk. This way you mimic the CBC logic, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Topaco Thank you a lot.
I post here the correct merge code with CBC logic.

```php
$resql = $db->query($sql);

if ($resql === false) {
    die("Erreur lors de la requête SQL : " . $db->lasterror());
}
 
$key = $db->fetch_object($resql);
print $key->pass_crypted . "\n";
$key->pass_crypted = substr($key->pass_crypted, 0, 32);
print $key->pass_crypted . "\n";

if ($key === false) {
    die("Aucune clé n'a été trouvée dans la base de données.");
}
 
$outputFilePath = $outputdir . "/c" . $file . ".gz";

// Vérification si le fichier source existe
$sourceFilePath = $outputdir . "/" . $file . ".gz";
if (!file_exists($sourceFilePath)) {
    die("Le fichier source n'existe pas : " . $sourceFilePath);
}

// Solution par morceau
// Ouvrir le fichier source en lecture
$sourceFile = fopen($sourceFilePath, 'r');
if (!$sourceFile) {
    die("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier source : $sourceFilePath");
}

// Ouvrir le fichier de sortie en écriture
$outputFile = fopen($outputFilePath, 'w');
if (!$outputFile) {
    die("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier de sortie : $outputFilePath");
}

// Définir la taille du morceau (en octets)
$chunkSize = 1024; // 1 Mo

$iv = '';

while (!feof($sourceFile)) {
    // Vecteur d'initialisation (IV) (128 bits, 16 octets)
    if ($iv === '') {
        // Premier bloc, on génère un IV aléatoire
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        fwrite($outputFile, $iv);
    } else if ($encryptedChunk) {
        // Bloc suivant, on récupère les 16 derneiers bits du dernier bloc chiffré
        $iv = substr($encryptedChunk, -16);
    } else {
        die("Erreur lors de la génération du vecteur d'initialisation.");
    }

    // Lire un morceau du fichier source
    $chunk = fread($sourceFile, $chunkSize);
    if ($chunk === false) {
        die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier source.");
    }

    // Chiffrer le morceau
    $encryptedChunk = openssl_encrypt($chunk, 'aes-256-cbc', $key->pass_crypted, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    if ($encryptedChunk === false) {
        die("Erreur lors du chiffrement du morceau.");
    }

    // Écrire le morceau chiffré dans le fichier de sortie
    if (fwrite($outputFile, $encryptedChunk) === false) {
        die("Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier chiffré.");
    }
}

// Fermer les fichiers
fclose($sourceFile);
fclose($outputFile);

echo "Le fichier a été chiffré avec succès.\n";

// Supprimer le fichier source
if (!unlink($sourceFilePath)) {
    die("Erreur lors de la suppression du fichier source.");
}

/*
 * Fin Chiffrement de l'archive (symétrique)
 */


$key2 = $key->pass_crypted; //Modifiable
print "flag_key : ";
$flag_key = $key->pass_crypted == $key2;
var_dump($flag_key);
print "\n";

$inputFilePath = $outputFilePath; //Modifiable

$decryptedFilePath = $outputdir . "/" . $file . ".gz"; //Modifiable

// Vérification si le fichier chiffré existe
if (!file_exists($inputFilePath)) {
    die("Le fichier chiffré n'existe pas : " . $inputFilePath);
}

// Ouvrir le fichier chiffré
if (! $encryptedFile = fopen($inputFilePath, "r")) {
    die("Erreur lors de l'ouverture du fichier chiffré.");
}

//Ouvrir le fichier déchiffré
if (! $decryptedFile = fopen($decryptedFilePath, "w")) {
    die("Erreur lors de l'ouverture du fichier déchiffré.");
}

$chunkSize = 1024 + 16;

$iv2 = '';

// Ecriture du fichier déchiffré
while (!feof($encryptedFile)) {
    // Récupération de l'IV (16 dernies octets du chunk)
    if ($iv2 == '') {
        // Pour le premier bloc on récupère les 16 premiers octets du fichier
        $iv2 = fread($encryptedFile, 16);
    } else if ($encryptedData) {
        // Pour les blocs suivants on récupère les 16 derniers octets du bloc précédent
        $iv2 = substr($encryptedData, -16);
    } else {
        die("Erreur lors de la génération du vecteur d'initialisation.");
    }

    if (! $encryptedData = fread($encryptedFile, $chunkSize)) {
        die("Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier chiffré.");
    }

    $decryptedData = openssl_decrypt($encryptedData, 'aes-256-cbc', $key2, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv2);

    if ($decryptedData === false) {
        print openssl_error_string();
        die("Erreur lors du déchiffrement.\n");
    }
    
    if (! fwrite($decryptedFile, $decryptedData)) {
        die("Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier déchiffré.");
    }
}

echo "Le fichier a été déchiffré avec succès dans : " . $decryptedFilePath . "\n";
```

Comment: It is great that your question is resolved. You should explain what you had to do/change instead of just posting the code. That allows the answer to help future visitors too.

Comment: I change the chunk size for decrypt (1024 -> 1024 + 16 bytes). And to use cbc logic I use the end of the last bloc (16 bytes) like a IV to encrypt my next bloc.